# How to properly delimit multiple images before sending them over a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

let's say I need to send, for instance, five images from a client to a server over a socket and that I want to do it at once (not sending one and waiting for an ACK).

**Questions:**

1. I'd like to know if there are some best practices or guidelines for delimiting the end of each one.
2. What would be the safest approach for detecting the delimiters and processing each image once in the server? (In **C/C++** if possible)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first send the length in bytes and then the image? This eliminates the delemiter?

Comment: depends on the protocol

Comment: @DavidFeurle my problem is that I don't know for sure the length of the image that the client would sent, the most approximate thing that I tried is to send `fileInputStream.available();` (client is in Java), but even the documentation says is just an estimated number of bytes...

Comment: You can *always* get the size of a file. Either use some other file handling function to "stat" the file, or simply seek to the end of the file stream and get the offset from the start which is the size.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the ideas, I will research a little for the way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since images are binary data, it would be difficult to come up with delimiter that cannot be contained in the image. (And ultimately confusing the receiving side)

I would advice you to create a header that would be placed at the beginning of the transmission, or at the beginning of each image.

An example:

```
struct Header
{
    uint32_t ImageLength;
//  char ImageName[128];
} __attribute__(packed);
```

The sender should prepend this before each image and fill in the length correctly. The receiver would then know when the image ends and would expect another Header structure at that position.

The **attribute**(packed) is a safety, that makes sure the header will have the same alignment even if you compile server and client with different GCC versions. It's recomended in cases where structures are interpreted by different processes.

Data Stream:
Header
Image Data
Header
Image Data
Header
Image Data
...

Comment: The __attribute__(packed) is a GCC specific extension, but each compiler has an equivalent to it.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant idea, but I still don't see clearly how I would detect safely the header of each image...

Comment: I think I would prefer a header/protocol that transmitted the length in an endian-proof manner.

Comment: Basically, header is what you expect as the first thing that comes over socket. You know it's size: sizeof(struct Header). So you read out that many bytes, and you know it's the header.

Comment: Finally I ended up using something similar to that, the difference being in that I send the image length always with 5 bytes before every image. To get exactly the length on Java I read and count the bytes before starting to send: 
`int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      imgLength+=bytesRead;
      while (bytesRead > 0)  
   {
   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 
   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize); 
   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
   imgLength+=bytesRead;
   }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use these function to send files (from client in java) to a server (in C). The idea is to send 4 bytes which indicates the file's size followed by the file content, when all files have been sent, send 4 bytes (all set to 0 zero) to indicate the end of the transfer.

```
// Compile with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008

// path, if not empty, must be ended with a path separator '/'
// for example: "C:/MyImages/"
int receiveFiles(SOCKET sck, const char *pathDir)
{
    int fd;
    long fSize=0;
    char buffer[8 * 1024];
    char filename[MAX_PATH];
    int count=0;

    // keep on receiving until we get the appropiate signal 
    // or the socket has an error
    while (true)
    {
        if (recv(sck, buffer, 4, 0) != 4)
        {
            // socket is closed or has an error
            // return what we've received so far
            return count; 
        }
        fSize = (int) ((buffer[0] & 0xff) << 24) |
                (int) ((buffer[1] & 0xff) << 16) |
                (int) ((buffer[2] & 0xff) <<  8) |
                (int)  (buffer[3] & 0xff);
        if (fSize == 0) 
        {
            // received final signal
            return count; 
        }
        sprintf(filename, "%sIMAGE_%d.img", pathDir, count+1);
        fd = _creat(filename, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
        int iReads;
        int iRet;
        int iLeft=fSize;
        while (iLeft > 0)
        {
            if (iLeft > sizeof(buffer)) iReads = sizeof(buffer);
            else iReads=iLeft;
            if ((iRet=recv(sck, buffer, iReads, 0)) <= 0)
            {
                _close(fd);
                // you may delete the file or leave it to inspect
                // _unlink(filename); 
                return count; // socket is closed or has an error
            }
            iLeft-=iRet;
            _write(fd, buffer, iRet);
        }
        count++;
        _close(fd);
    }
}
```

The client part

```
/**
 * Send a file to a connected socket.
 * <p>
 * First it send the file size if 4 bytes then the file's content.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Note: File size is limited to a 32bit signed integer, 2GB
 * </p>
 * 
 * @param os
 *           OutputStream of the connected socket
 * @param fileName
 *           The complete file's path of the image to send
 * @throws Exception
 * @see {@link receiveFile} for an example on how to receive the file from the other side.
 * 
 */
public void sendFile(OutputStream os, String fileName) throws Exception
{
    // File to send
    File myFile = new File(fileName);
    int fSize = (int) myFile.length();
    if (fSize == 0) return; // No empty files
    if (fSize < myFile.length())
    {
        System.out.println("File is too big'");
        throw new IOException("File is too big.");
    }

    // Send the file's size
    byte[] bSize = new byte[4];
    bSize[0] = (byte) ((fSize & 0xff000000) >> 24);
    bSize[1] = (byte) ((fSize & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
    bSize[2] = (byte) ((fSize & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
    bSize[3] = (byte) (fSize & 0x000000ff);
    // 4 bytes containing the file size
    os.write(bSize, 0, 4);

    // In case of memory limitations set this to false
    boolean noMemoryLimitation = true;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    try
    {
        if (noMemoryLimitation)
        {
            // Use to send the whole file in one chunk
            byte[] outBuffer = new byte[fSize];
            int bRead = bis.read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length);
            os.write(outBuffer, 0, bRead);
        }
        else
        {
            // Use to send in a small buffer, several chunks
            int bRead = 0;
            byte[] outBuffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            while ((bRead = bis.read(outBuffer, 0, outBuffer.length)) > 0)
            {
                os.write(outBuffer, 0, bRead);
            }
        }
        os.flush();
    }
    finally
    {
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

To send the files from the client:

```
try
{
    // The file name must be a fully qualified path
    sendFile(mySocket.getOutputStream(), "C:/MyImages/orange.png");
    sendFile(mySocket.getOutputStream(), "C:/MyImages/lemmon.png");
    sendFile(mySocket.getOutputStream(), "C:/MyImages/apple.png");
    sendFile(mySocket.getOutputStream(), "C:/MyImages/papaya.png");
    // send the end of the transmition
    byte[] buff = new byte[4];
    buff[0]=0x00;
    buff[1]=0x00;
    buff[2]=0x00;
    buff[3]=0x00;
    mySocket.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, 4);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although a little too complex for what I was expecting surely I've learnt things from it

Comment: @Str1101 you're wellcome. Please see the edited I've made to the code, the C function `receiveFiles()` need a star at *pathDir.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot easily send a header containing the length, use some likely delimiter. If the images are not compressed and consist of bitmap-stype data, maybe 0xFF/0XFFFF/0xFFFFFFF as fully-saturated luminance values are usually rare?

Use an escape-sequence to eliminate any instances of the delimiter that turn up inside your data.

This does mean iterating all the data at both ends, but depending on your data flows, and what is being done anyway, it may be a useful solution :(

Comment: Can you give me an example or advice of how to use an escape-sequence in this case, please?

Comment: Iterate all your data.  If you find [ESC], replace it with [ESC],[ESC]. If you find 0xff, replace it with [ESC],[0xff]. Append an un-escaped 0xff at end. Do the opposite at the server, 'undoing' the escape-sequences until you find an un-escaped 0xFF and so know you're reached end of frame.

Comment: Surely, this involves much more work than a length header - iterating all the data and copying to insert the escape-sequences, but if your data is coming in at the client in small chunks and you want to forward them to the server ASAP, an escape-sequnce would likely be quicker end-to-end than buffering up whole frames at the client in order to determine the length before sending anything at all.